# wordpress comments showing on all articles bug?

Tags: wordpress

One of my clients have a problem with a wordpress website. It seams that all the comments on a article in a specific category shows up on all articles on that category.

How can i fix that ? What should i look for ?

Comment: show the code where you place the comment template

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look to the single file in your theme then you could find which template the comment use.
Once you find the template check the code may something is going wrong on it like its only get the comments form on post_id.
If not you need check theme functions.php 
For example on twentyfifteen:
The single file is : single.php and the comment template came from comments_template() function which using comments.php in the same theme.

Comment: comments_template( '', true );   -->this is the code that inserts the comments ? it's ok ?

Comment: Yes, this should load the comments.php in the same theme directory

Comment: In your comments.php, check if you found wp_list_comments() print here the arguments to check

Comment: here you are:wp_list_comments('type=comment&callback=custom_comments');

Comment: This function calling back another function ( custom_comments ) you should find this function on functions.php

Comment: I think this function is added by disqus comment plugin. I've instaled disqus hoping that will solve that problem with no success...(In default wordpress comment system and using disquss too) :(

Comment: Did you find custom_comments function on the theme function ?

Comment: no, isnt in functions.php in my theme..now i search for it in entire wp-content folder..:(

Comment: Okay, if you did not find it try to remove ( &callback=custom_comments )

Comment: somehow custom_comments functions is in items/comments.php

Comment: is too long to post here...where should i post ?

Comment: actually modifing or deleting the comments.php in theme or items folder have no effect...this is so so strange...i should disable disquss comment plugin maybe to debug more...but the site is in production right now and is harder to do that